# Microsoft Word - How can I specify table margins (not cell paddings)?

Tags: microsoft-word

In Microsoft Word, how can I specify table margins (not cell paddings)?

I'm composing a 100+ pages of document and I don't want to add a new *Style* for paragraphs below every table.[image: Problem Screenshot]

I am using the latest Word of Office 365.

**[Update]**  *This question has been resolved*.  See the picture below and the answer by Cnread and his comment on it.

[image: Solution Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **Table Properties** dialog box, under **Text wrapping**, click **Around**, and then set the fields under the **Distance from surrounding text**. Since it appears that you're most concerned about space between the end of the table and the next text paragraph, you'd set the **Bottom** value.

If all your tables fill the whole area between the left and right text margins, this will do what you want. If some of your tables are narrower and you don't actually want text to wrap around them, you can set high **Left**/**Right** values to prevent this.

All in all, though, in terms of total effort required, it would almost certainly be easier just to create a new paragraph style for the first paragraph after a table; or redefine your usual text paragraph so that it has space above instead of below (or both space above and space below). For other changes to a table, you could create a new table style that you apply to all your tables (or modify an existing style); but the **Text wrapping** and **Distance from surrounding text** properties aren't something that can be set for a table style, so you'll have to manually set them for every table individually.

Comment: The problem is selecting **Text wrapping: Around** disables **Indent from left:"** right above.  As you can see in the screenshot, it's now grayed out.

Comment: @Culip: At the top of the **Table Positioning** dialog box, under **Horizontal**, set the **Position** field to the specific amount of indent you want (e.g., **0.13"**). That field is a combo box, meaning that you can type values in it in addition to selecting from the list of predefined values